# JavaScript - mCustomScrollbar

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

```
(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery(window).on("load", function () {

        jQuery("#inf-scroll-gallery").mCustomScrollbar({
            axis: "x",
            theme: "light-3",
            advanced: {
                autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I'm using the above script for custom scrollbar. Here it's working perfectly when we scroll on the content and also when we drag the scroll bar. But what I want is I need to scroll the content only when the scroll bar is moving. I'm sharing some links here for more clarity.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Also see the horizontal scrollbar. Here the images should only scroll when we drag that scrollbar. Can we do that?

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Comment: If my answer is not satisfying can you say what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Library supports this kind a problem
You can add mouseWheel:{ enable: false } property to your script

```
(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery(window).on("load", function () {

        jQuery("#inf-scroll-gallery").mCustomScrollbar({
            axis: "x",
            theme: "light-3",
             mouseWheel:{ enable: false }

            advanced: {
                autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can add mouseWheel property like 

$('#container2').mCustomScrollbar({ 
        theme:"dark-3",
        mouseWheel:{ enable: false }

});